# How can I embed a PApplet object into an ordinary applet?

Tags: java, applet, processing

I have a [Processing](http://www.processing.org) sketch written in Java (*not* the Processing IDE) and I would like to embed it into a Java applet which can be run by a web browser's java plugin.  Processing sketches are created by extending a class called PApplet which in turn extends Component, so in principle this should be quite easy.  Indeed, [this](http://www.sebastianoliva.com/en/en/2010/05/using-a-processing-sketch-as-a-java-component/trackback/index.html) guide explains how to embed it into a JFrame; [this](http://processing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/processing/build/javadoc/core/processing/core/PApplet.html) documentation is also relevant.  The problem is that I have very little experience with applets and I can't figure out how to modify the examples that I have.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).  It would be much easier to deploy this in a frame using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: Not for school: I'm coding against a pre-existing codebase.

Comment: *"Not for school:"*  That still does not make it a good idea.  Applets are (always have been, always will be) a PITA. *"I'm coding against a pre-existing codebase."*  Good but..  I don't see how that relates to anything I wrote.

Comment: It relates to what you wrote by answering your question, "Why code an applet?"  I'm consulting at a company that deploys its product using applets rather than JWS, and even if I had an opinion about the relative merits of the two technologies you can probably guess that they are not interested in me for my Java expertise.

Comment: OK well.. `PApplet` **is an applet** so it is 'easy' to deploy it in HTML as an embedded component.  But DYM you want to embed the `PApplet` into part of *another* applet?  That is doable, but more tricky.  *"they are not interested in me for my Java expertise"*  More fool them.  Why hire someone if not for their expertise?

Comment: Well, let's start with deploying it into HTML.  Assume that I have compiled a class MySketch which extends PApplet.  I put an HTML file in the same folder as MySketch.class and included the line <APPLET CODE="MySketch.class" WIDTH=600 HEIGHT=600>
</APPLET>.  When I load the HTML file in my browser, it loads the applet and then I see a blank grey 600 by 600 box, but the sketch does not appear.

Comment: To answer your other question: my training is in mathematics, and that is the expertise that they were most interested in.

Comment: *"I see a blank grey 600 by 600 box, but the sketch does not appear."*  Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show for applets & JWS apps.  If there is no output at the default level, raise it and try again.  *"my training is in mathematics"*  That does not bode well.  Applets can trip up even experienced **Java GUI developers**, as I outlined in that blog article..

Comment: I'm using OpenJDK in Ubuntu with the IcedTea plugin.  I'm not sure if IcedTea has similar security settings, but in any event my browser runs correctly the few test applets that I've written so far (just not the ones using Processing).

Comment: *"similar security settings"*  What?  The only 'settings' I mentioned related to a reporting level in the console.  Nothing to do with security.  *"..in any event my browser runs correctly the few test applets that I've written so far.."*  Good.  But again I don't see the relevance to getting information on why *this* applet fails.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what settings you're referring to or how to change them in IcedTea.  IcedTea does not seem to have a counterpart to Oracle's Java Console.  Regardless, I do not understand why plugin or browser level settings would distinguish between Applet and PApplet, given that PApplet is a subclass of Applet.

Comment: (sigh)  I should have known this would turn into a saga..  Really, https://www.google.com/search?q=+IcedTea+console should tell you a lot more about the console on a JRE I don't use.  OTOH Oracle's JREs are now available for all major platforms, so if you cannot figure how to get the Iced Tea console on-screen, I suggest you use the Oracle JRE for testing applets.  *"I do not understand why plugin or browser level settings would distinguish between Applet and PApplet, given that PApplet is a subclass of Applet."*  You really seem to be missing the point of 'settings' as I used it.  Read again.

Comment: I think at this point it is safe to interpret your comments as an elaborate way of saying "I don't know the answer to your question". Thanks anyway for trying.

Comment: *"I think at this point it is safe to interpret your comments as an elaborate way of saying "I don't know the answer to your question"."*  If by 'question' you mean *"Can anyone help?"*, my questions and comments to you have been directed towards **getting enough information** to know what the actual problem is.  Of course, there are other ways for me to get the information, but they involve *you* making the applet publicly available so *I* can visit it and get the information needed.  I just thought this might be more direct (*'teach a man to fish..'*).

Comment: @Paul Siegel Did my solution work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Andrew is right, PApplet `is a` Applet(generalization, extends, etc.) so basically all the functionalities an Applet has, your Processing PApplet will also have plus more. It's a matter of simply exporting the applet.

Processing 2.0 removed the **Export Applet** option, but it's still present in **Processing 1.5.1** which you can get from the *Stable Releases* [Porcessing downloads](https://processing.org/download/?processing)

Another alternative is using [eclipse](http://eclipse.org/downloads/) with the [Proclipsing](https://code.google.com/p/proclipsing/) plugin.
The plugin allows you to easily create a Processing project (PApplet subclass, etc.)
and also easily export an applet or application. Although heavier than the minimal Processing editor, you've got loads of nifty tools in eclipse like auto-complete and refactoring to name a few.

Looking at your question again, it looks slightly confusion: a chicken and egg problem: you want to use an Applet just because you want to embed your PApplet into an html container.
As Andrew mentioned, you can simply export your PApplet and embed it (the html file is also generated). 
Using your approach: using a separate Applet that contains a PApplet, you'd do something like this:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class CApplet extends Applet{

   public CApplet(){
       PApplet sketch = new YourPAppletClassNameHere();
       sketch.init();
       add(sketch);
   }
}
```

You would then need to export this applet, right ? Why do this and not simply export the PApplet in the first place ?

Comment: I think he thought he needed to wrap the PApplet in a regular Applet in order to export it. Great suggestions, though!

Comment: I thought that's what my code above does: there's a regular Applet class which through composition attaches a PApplet to itself. A PApplet itself should be 'embeddable' as a java applet on an html page since PApplet extends Applet and inherits it's functionalities

Comment: Yep! I was just answering your question at the end :) The OP was mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Two separate classes are needed:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class CApplet extends Applet
{
  public CApplet()
  {
    PApplet sketch = new MyP5Applet();
    sketch.init();
    add(sketch);
  }
}
```

AND

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class MyP5Applet extends PApplet
{
  public void setup()
  {
    size(100, 100);
    // ...
  }

  public void draw()
  {
    rect(10, 10, 80, 80);
    // ...
  }
}
```

Then just run CApplet (from Eclipse, AppletRunner, HTML, or whatever)

Comment: I try to do this in max/msp but the processing Applet doesn't appear. Do you have any idea what to do?